# python double for in list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have checked the other questions but here I found something very strange.

if I make the two for loop in a list comprehension it works well.

```
pools = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]

# print(result)
# result = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

But if I break it down into normal nested for loop it will be an endless code.

```
pools = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    for x in result:
        for y in pool:
            result.append(x + [y])

# This will be an endless looping
```

I guess it may because there are some hidden code in the python list comprehension?
Really appreciate for your kindness help.

I have modified the nested for loop but still seems not work.

```
pools = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
result = [[]]
temp = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    for x in result:
        for y in pool:
            temp.append(x + [y])
result = temp

# result = [[], [0], [1], [2], [0], [1], [2]]
```

Comment: The list comprehension creates a new list and finally assigns it to `result`. The second sample modifies the list while the for-loop iterates over it (bad!).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Please post this as an answer. Thank!

Comment: Really appreciate for you answer, sorry to ask but could you please give any hint on how to rewrite the list comprehension into normal for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code sample the list comprehension is executed first and the finally created list is assigned to `result`.

In the second example the list referenced by `result` is modified while the second for-loop iterates over it. Always appending new items to `result` in the loop ensures that the for-loop won't ever exhaust the list.

The list comprehension can be rewritten with conventional for-loops as:

```
pools = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    temp = []     # Begin of rewritten list comprehension
    for x in result:
        for y in pool:
            temp.append(x + [y])

    result = temp # Final assignment of constructed list
```